# HTML use with PHP

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Hi I've started learning PHP in hoped of developing my own bespoke Wordpress - I'm familiar with html/css/javascript (a little) and jquery but when developing a wordpress theme, it seems that all the files are php files, or alot of them at least so I was wondering how I will be making use of html/css in a php file?

Comment: http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/qt/php_with_html.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going to be easy if you already know HTML and CCS/JS.

Your php file content would have something like:

```
<html>
<head><script></script><style></style></head>
<body>
...
<?php
/* PHP CODE HERE */
 echo "<h1>";
 echo "Hello World;";
 echo "</h1>";
?>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Another important thing is that you are going to need a php server like apache, I recommend you using [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/es/xampp-windows.html), it has an easy control panel. 
[XAMPP Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1dskkC1wdI).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make you php file look like a html one, try this:

```
<?php

echo '<html>
<head><script></script><style></style></head>
<body>';

echo "<h1>";
echo "Hello World;";
echo "</h1>";

echo '</body></html>';
?>
```

When you check to source you will only see what is echoed.
[click here for more info](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp)